# Reading linked list from file in C

Tags: c, file, pointers, linked-list, fread

I'm supposed to read this linked list of pointers from a file.
Problem is that whenever `fread()` is called it changes not only the pointer *p, but *poly aswell, then it causes `addNVertex()` to crash the program. Read polygon method:

```
Polygon* readPolygon(FILE *file){
    Polygon *poly=initPoly();
    Point p;
    int numofvertice,i;
    fread(&numofvertice,sizeof(int),1,file);
    for(i=0;i<numofvertice;i++){
        fread(&p,sizeof(Point),1,file);
        addNVertex(poly,&p,i+1);
    }
    return poly;
}
```

It is a binary file looking something like this:
`int,point,point...,int,point,point...`
The int represents the number of points to add to the polygon.

An example: if *poly was 0x8000 before the 2nd `fread()` (after `initPoly()`) , after the second `fread()` it changes to other value even though I read the data to &p???
I've been debugging this for the past hour still nothing comes up...

[image: The issue]

Comment: `Polygon *poly = malloc` ... `poly = initPoly();`. Memory leak.

Comment: wow right missed that one, still doesn't fix my issue

Comment: But you're assigning to a pointer by `malloc` and then assigning something else to that pointer. The memory allocated by `malloc` is lost. What's the implementation of `initPoly`?

Comment: I already said you are right mate :>

Comment: btw this didn't fix my issue

Comment: This might help: take a look into your addNVertex function, make sure you copy contents of p (second argument) as you're using the same address again to get new content from file

Comment: not sure I understood what you meant but addNVertex doesn't do anything to the addresses of the pointers. It just changes the fields data (assigns the pointer value of p to the N item on the list and fixes referrences), its like when I'm sending p to addNVertex it just utterly forgets what `malloc` allocated and assigns new value after `fread()`

Comment: @anthony-Arnold I prefer to call it memory peeing.

Comment: Just a recommendation for portable code: When reading data from a file you should never ever read it directly into structs. Padding, endianess and different sizes of the types will sooner or later break your code. Casting or copying raw memory into structs and types looks tempting but is not portable across different architecture and compilers. `sizeof(int)` is also not guaranteed to be the same everywhere.

Comment: Agreed, this is an assignment though :)

Comment: Updates: tried using `Point p` instead of `Point *p` with `&`, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I gave up so I did a workaround. I wrote field by field, then `malloc()`ing the Polygon, then reading field by field and populate Polygon.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
Point *p=(Point*)malloc(sizeof(Point));
...
fread(&p,sizeof(Point),1,file);
```

The call to `fread` reads in data from the file and stores it at the memory occupied by the pointer `p`.  `p` is a local variable on the stack and likely has a size of 4 or 8 bytes, depending on your program's bitness.  But you're reading in `sizeof(Point)` bytes; if `Point` is larger than a pointer, you're smashing the stack with a buffer overrun.

You really meant to write this:

```
//    V-- No "&" here
fread(p,sizeof(Point),1,file);
```

This reads the file data into *the memory pointed to be `p`*, not the pointer object `p` itself.  Since you actually have `sizeof(Point)` bytes worth of data there, this does not write out of bounds.

You're also failing to free the memory you've allocated here, but that memory leak is an entirely separate issue.

Comment: Good eye.  I totally missed that.

Comment: thanks for the elaboration, i'm not freeing the memory because i'm still using it? if i free p then my linked list will have a pointer pointing to where the p pointed where there's nothing (unless i have no idea what i'm saying?)
btw didn't work neither. actually everything worked perfectly before i changed `Point *p` to `Point p` and used & this time.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is declared as a pointer. Thus using `&p` in the `fread` call will not read into the memory where `p` points to, but change the `p` pointer itself. It causes both a memory overflow trashing your `numofvertice` and `i` variables (and possibly more) and store an invalid memory address in `p`. Just `fread` into `p` and not into `&p`:

```
fread(p, sizeof(Point), 1, file);
```

Comment: Those are those kind of errors that are hard to figure out.  Good eye.

Comment: thanks, but as i've replied earlier that didn't work neither. now it doesn't even load the point properly...

Comment: It could be many things that might still be wrong. Uninitialized memory (use `calloc` instead of `malloc`), padding issues (use `#pragma pack(1)` for the Point struct or class), wrong type sizes (use types defined in `stdint.h`) etc. p.p. - Reading `sizeof(Point)` bytes of data into `Point&` was definitely wrong though. Even if this is only an assignment you should better learn to code right. Never cast memory to structs unless you are working with Kernel API or doing IPC stuff on the same machine. God kills a kitten every time you do. :-(

Comment: well that is the only way i was taught so there are not many options left for me. I agree they teach kinder garden coding but the standards are not up to me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using dynamic memory allocation for `p`, you can just use stack variable

```
Point p;
```

Then the second fread will be valid

```
fread(&p,sizeof(Point),1,file);
```

You may also need to change to

```
addNVertex(poly, &p, i+1);
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense that `p` and `poly` are sharing memory.

Comment: @MuliYulzary: What do you mean by "didn't work"? What error do you get if you use `Point p;` to create variable on stack? What function signature does `addNVertex` look like? I assume it is something like `void addNVertex(Polygon*, Point*, int)`.

Comment: Percisely. one more thing: if i need p accessible outside the function should i use malloc?
And the error is the same error tonga, I can add another screenshot if you'd like

Comment: No, stack variables are local in function only and is not accessible from outside. But from you original post, I only see the `Polygon` struct is returned, not `p`. So I don't know what is inside the `addNVertex` function.

Comment: addNVertex simply points the field (nextpoint) to the point sent